# Quitar repetidos en una matriz en C

Tags: c

Vuelvo a publicarlo porque el otro post quedo muy abajo y nadie me contesto :(
Necesito sacarle los numeros repetidos a una matriz generada con numeros aleatorios

Los numeros aleatorios generados:

```
    void generarCarton (int m[3][5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = 1 + rand () % 91;
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: No dupliques preguntas, no es necesario. Te invito a leer [ask]. Los fines de semana es común que poca gente se conecte. Debes tener paciencia. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es simple, solo debes comparar cada elemento de la matriz con sus anteriores, en caso de estar repetido lo cambias y comparas de nuevo con todos los  anteriores para asegurarte de que el nuevo número no sea repetido.

```
void noRepeat(int m[3][5]){
    int lista[15];
    int nR = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
            for(int k = 0;k<nR;k++){
                if(m[i][j] == lista[k]){
                    m[i][j] = 1 + rand () % 91;
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
            lista[nR++] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso yo utilizo una lista, de modo que cada elemento que no se repite lo guardo ahí y las comparaciones las hago con la lista por el echo de que es más sencillo comprender visualmente que usar comparaciones directas con la matriz y poner de nuevo 2 for anidados con dos indices.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu codigo funciona perfectamente, pero hay algo que no logro entender, que vendria a hacer la linea en la que esta:
lista[nR++] = m[i][j];

Comment: Esa línea hace referencia a que cuando se encuentra un número no repetido se agrega a el arreglo y se incrementa en 1 en contador de cuantos números hay en la lista de no repetidos. nR++ es un posIncremento por ende agrega el elemento m[i][j]  en la posición nR y después se aumenta nR

Comment: Hola denso, luego de usar varias veces ese algoritmo, me di cuenta de que los numeros se repiten, pero no es tan habitual, sin eso y cargando 15 numeros con un rand()%16, se repiten alrededor de 4 o 5 veces, pero con el algoritmo se repiten 2 o 1 vez, tenes idea de porque podria ser? Muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora mismo no puedo a alisar el algoritmo a fondo, pero un error podría ser que k=0 daría un error ya que el for daría lugar a que por su posIncremento realmente k al final del if sea igual a 1 y no se evalúe el primer elemento, por ende una solución seria cambiar k=0 por k=-1

Comment: Hola @denso, gracias por tu rapida respuesta, me siguen dando repetidos despues de poner que k=-1

Comment: He ejecutado aproximadamente 30 veces el código y me ha funcionado correctamente, no me salen números repetidos en la matriz, incluso reduje el 90 a 16 para forzar repetidos y aun así me funciona correctamente. Lo unico que se me ocurre que podria estar pasando es que srand(time(NULL)), lo tengas en la función o en ambito global, cambialo para que este dentro del main. De ahí ya no puedo hacer más por ti

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentare buscar una alternativa, se me ocurre intentar apartarlo en una funcion distinta, muy util y gracias por responder rapido. +1